# VBA: function to get difference from birth date and other date using DateDiff

Tags: excel, vba, loops, date, datediff

I broke my head to get the date difference between two Dates, but at the beginning I had constant problems, for example:

If the month was the same in both values ​​to be compared, the result was the negative days.
Or in some cases where it should be differences of 2 months and 30 days, it managed to have results like 3 months and 1 days, how?

well an example would be the following:
date1 = "02/15/2020"
date2 = "11/16/2019"

where in the end I got
month = 3
day = 1
why?
because at the end of 11 from 2019 to 2 of 2020 there are 3 months ... and day = 1 because of 16 - 15 are 1 (?) and if the date was a "11/14/2019" you would get a: day = -1

In the end I managed to solve all my problems with the following code:

```
Public Function GetDiffDate(birthdate As Date, otherDate As Date) As Variant
Dim CurrentDate, Years, ThisYear, Months, ThisMonth, Days

CurrentDate = CDate(birthdate )
Years = DateDiff("yyyy", CurrentDate, otherDate ) - 1
ThisYear = DateAdd("yyyy", Years, otherDate )
Months = DateDiff("m", ThisYear, otherDate )
ThisMonth = DateAdd("m", Months, ThisYear)
Days = DateDiff("d", ThisMonth, otherDate )

Do While (Days < 0) Or (Days > 0 And Months = 12) Or (Months < 0) Or (Months = 12) Or (Years < 0)

'> Here I can deduce if the days are negative, if so, then reduce the
'> account by one month and re-draw the days of difference

If Days < 0 Then 
                If Months > 0 Then Months = Months - 1
                ThisMonth = DateAdd("m", Months, ThisYear)
                Days = DateDiff("d", ThisMonth, otherDate ) * -1
            End If
            If Months < 0 Then
                ThisYear = DateAdd("yyyy", Years, CurrentDate)
                Months = DateDiff("m", ThisYear, otherDate )
                ThisMonth = DateAdd("m", Months, ThisYear)
                Days = DateDiff("d", ThisMonth, otherDate )
            End If

            If Days > 0 And Months = 12 Then
                If Years >= 0 Then Years = Years + 1
                Months = 0
            ThisMonth = DateAdd("m", Months, ThisYear)
            End If

            If Months = 12 And Days = 0 Then
                    Years = Years + 1
                    Months = 0
            End If
        Loop
    End Function
```

Example
The mistakes I had were like this:
birthDate = "02/15/2019"
otherDate = "02/16/2020"

with this code i get:

```
Years = DateDiff ("yyyy", CurrentDate, otherDate)
     ThisYear = DateAdd ("yyyy", Years, otherDate)
     Months = DateDiff ("m", ThisYear, otherDate)
     ThisMonth = DateAdd ("m", Months, ThisYear)
     Days = DateDiff ("d", ThisMonth, otherDate)
```

Results:

> Years = 1 Months = 3 Days = -1

but the real value should be

> Years = 0, Months = 2, Days = 30

For this I implemented my while do and if conditions to adjust the result as it should be.
But my question is:

> If there is another way to make this more elegant?

I appreciate it and greetings!

Comment: What do you want the result to be in, number of days?

Comment: I just need numbers@Bankar

Comment: `Debug.Print DateDiff("d", #1/16/2019#, #2/15/2020#)` will give `395`

Comment: Can't you just minus the dates? Assume Cell A1 = 2/15/2020, B1 = 11/16/2019. A1-B1 gives you 91, meaning the difference is 91 days

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand your previous question, i'm trying are getting days, month, year in numbers.  @Bankar

Comment: For that, I use DateAdd to generate a future date using the month and day of the birthday date, to be able to compare This future date with otherDate and get something more accurate and eliminate unnecessary days?   @Bankar

Comment: Sorry mate, you lost me completely, can you edit the question to include samples? and what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok got you. You can use formula for this. Let's assume Cell A1 contains 2/15/2020 and Cell B1 contains 11/16/2019

```
To get the day only difference: =DATEDIF(B1,A1,"md")

To get the month only difference: =DATEDIF(B1,A1,"ym")

To get the year only difference: =DATEDIF(B1,A1,"y")
```

So if you want it to show in one cell, you can combine them like below:

```
=DATEDIF(B1,A1,"md") & " day(s), "&DATEDIF(B1,A1,"ym")&" month(s), "&DATEDIF(B1,A1,"y")&" year(s)" 

This will output 30 day(s), 2 month(s), 0 year(s)
```